# Admin credential issue when encrypting files

Tags: c#, installshield

I am using rijndael encryption method to encrypt configuration file to keep it safe in client system. But after encryption, when a new file is generated, it comes with admin credential and i am not able to read it.

```
 public  void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {

        try
        {
            string password = @"myKey"; // Your Key Here
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

            string cryptFile = outputFile;
            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

            int data;
            while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);


            fsIn.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(inputFile);
            fi.Delete();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Encryption failed!", "Error");
        }
    }
```

I am using this method. When i run it in build mode it works perfectly but when i create a setup it fails and creates encrypted file with admin credential which i am not able to read. I am Using Install Shield 2013 limited edition.

Comment: i also tried manifest option.

Comment: So at the end of your encryptfile function there, you need to change the access rights to it surely? as that must be running as admin

Comment: but it works in build mode so why i need to change that.

Comment: under build mode, Im guessing it runs it as you with "run as admin" maybe under setup its actually running more as administrator than you.

Comment: no under both situation it runs with same credential.